# unknown attribute username where username does exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise, cucumber

On my rails project I try to swith from email login to username login with the devise gem.
As far I did all the steps but when I do cucumber I see this output:

```
Given a user "Aslak" exists         
# features/step_definitions/login_steps.rb:16
  unknown attribute: username (ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError)
  ./features/step_definitions/login_steps.rb:17:in `/^a user "(.*?)" exists$/'
  features/login.feature:4:in `Given a user "Aslak" exists'
```

The Given a user ¨Aslak¨ exist looks like this :

```
Given /^a user "(.*?)" exists$/ do |user_name|
  @user = User.create!(:username => user_name, :password => "s3cr3t")
end
```

But when I do rails c

```
u = User.first
```

I see this output:

```
=> #<User id: 1, email: "aslak@tamarawobben.nl", encrypted_password: "$2a$10$XjYgPtD4Ol4/sEpe934O6.yPcxs.jBF.m9SNTV.qhJp4...", reset_password_token: nil, reset_password_sent_at: nil, remember_created_at: nil, sign_in_count: 3, current_sign_in_at: "2012-11-05 20:27:44", last_sign_in_at: "2012-11-05 19:35:00", current_sign_in_ip: "127.0.0.1", last_sign_in_ip: "127.0.0.1", created_at: "2012-11-03 20:21:54", updated_at: "2012-11-06 07:58:36", username: "asLak">
```

So it looks like to me that username is existing.

Anyone a idea how to solve this ?

Roelof

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you need to compare case-insensitively, whilst ruby compares case-sensitively by default. This should solve your problem here:

```
Given /^a user "(.*?)" exists$/ do |user_name|
    @user = User.create!(:username => user_name.downcase! , :password => "s3cr3t")
end
```

Are you running a migration (below) before running the test?

```
env RAILS_ENV=test rake db:migrate
```

Comment: Sorry to see but it don't solve my problem. The error message is still there.

Comment: When I delete the :username => user_name part the error is gone. So it seems to be a problem there. But I don't see why that part is the problem

Comment: Make sure you have a username column in the users table and that it is in accordance with the rails conventions.

Comment: Sorry but I have that. See the output of User.first. Or do I misunderstood your message

Comment: No, in the database itself, is there a column username corresponding to the rails conventions, I'd go digging through the [devise source](https://github.com/plataformatec/devis) to get an answer to this one if you can't figure it out from your code

Comment: He, I see something strange. In the development database there is a column username but in the test database there is not a column username.

Comment: See my last edit. Or run the tests as rake test, which will take care of dropping/recreating the database.

Comment: The error is gone. Now I have to deal with email can't be blank error message.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any chance you edited an existing migration and forgot to run `rake db:test:clone` to propagate your changes to the  test database?

`rails c` runs in development, which uses another database. Check the result of `User.first` after running `rails c test` instead.